# Custom Picker Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, picker

I'm trying to search how to create a custom picker on Xamarin but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is what I want to do

[image]

I don't even know if I need to install a nuget package. Please help and thanks.

Comment: see https://www.hiimray.co.uk/2019/10/14/xamarin-forms-quick-and-easy-custom-picker-with-a-more-traditional-look/297

Comment: @Skalpel02 it sais PickerRenderer is deprecated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Picker Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519896/custom-picker-xamarin-android)

Comment: @Skalpel02 The thing is I don't know how to use it on my view

Comment: See doc [Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/). The `Introduction` page has an example of a customized entry `public class MyEntry : Entry ...` and xaml `<local:MyEntry ...>`. In your case, it would be similar to `public class MyPicker : Picker ...` with `<local:MyPicker ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Skalpel02, you need to sub-class the `Picker` class and implement the corresponding `Renderer`s in each platform. There, you have the ability to interact with native APIs of the platform.

Comment: I'm following the link he provided but it is giving error on `ElementChangedEventArgs` on my `OnElementChanged` Android renderer class method

Comment: @robluc - Add to your question the code you now have, and the exact error message (copy/paste its text). IMPORTANT: The android custom renderer class must be in your `.Android` project (not in the project that has the xaml files).

Comment: @robluc - Maybe [this xamgirl picker example](https://xamgirl.com/picker-with-right-side-icon-in-xamarin-forms/) will help you understand how to work with picker custom renderers.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'm following that link. I'm hoping that will work, thanks!

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have followed that code but it gives me error on the image. Mine it's an svg. Why is that happening? It's giving null reference

Comment: Using an svg requires [extra code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158751/how-to-use-svg-images-correctly-in-xamarin-forms-android). I recommend first getting it to work with a png.

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented by [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

**First**,a custom Picker control can be created by subclassing the Picker control, as shown in the following code:

```
    public class BorderlessPicker : Picker
    {
        public BorderlessPicker() : base()
        {
        }
    }
```

**Second**:Create the Custom Renderer on each Platform,Override the `OnElementChanged` method and write logic to customize the control,then Add an `ExportRenderer` attribute to the custom renderer class to specify that it will be used.

**In Android:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderlessPicker), typeof(BordlessPickerRenderer))]
 namespace AppPicker01.Droid
{
public class BordlessPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    public BordlessPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            Control.Background = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**In iOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderlessPicker), typeof(BorderlessPickerRenderer))]
namespace AppPicker01.iOS
   {
         public class BorderlessPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least, consume the custom picker control in Xaml:

```
  <apppicker01:BorderlessPicker Title="Select a color" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColorName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

MS official docs link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your own control that doesn't need a renderer and works on iOS, Android, and UWP. Here my solution.
You have to create a View "PickerCustom" for the control

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="___YOURCLASS"
             xmlns:xmleditor="clr-namespace:XmlEditor" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#ddd">
    <StackLayout x:Name="stack" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="1" BackgroundColor="#fff" Padding="5">
        <Label Text="{Binding TextValue}" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <ImageButton BackgroundColor="#ffffff" Source="dropdown.png" x:Name="img" WidthRequest="20"></ImageButton>
        <Entry WidthRequest="0"></Entry>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

with this code behind

```
public partial class PickerCustom : ContentView
    {
        public PickerCustom()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<CustomItem>();
            SelectedIndex = -1;
            BindingContext = this;

            TapGestureRecognizer tap0 = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tap0.Tapped +=  (sender, e) =>
            {
                img.Focus();

                PickerCustomList pcl = new PickerCustomList();
                pcl.Items = this.Items;
                App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(pcl);
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PickerCustomList>(this, "finish", (sender1) =>
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<PickerCustomList>(this, "finish");
                    img.Focus();
                    if(((PickerCustomList)sender1).SelectedIndex != -1)
                    {
                        SelectedIndex = ((PickerCustomList)sender1).SelectedIndex;
                    }
                });
            };
            GestureManager.AddGesture(stack, tap0);
        }

        string _textvalue = "";
        public string TextValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _textvalue;
            }
            set
            {
                _textvalue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CustomItem> Items { get; set; }

        int _selectedIndex = 0;
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedIndex = value;
                if(_selectedIndex>= Items.Count)
                {
                    _selectedIndex = -1;
                } else if (_selectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    TextValue = Items[SelectedIndex].Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    TextValue = "";
                }
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }  
    }

    public class CustomItem
    {
        public CustomItem(string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
        }

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
```

And a View "PickerCustomList" for the choice

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="___YOURCLASS" BackgroundColor="#66aaaaaa"
             x:Name="ContentPage1" Padding="30,100,30,100" >
    <ListView x:Name="ContactsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsVisible="True"
                VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.Header  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#f0f0f0" >
                <ImageButton Source="close.png" WidthRequest="20"  Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="10,5,10,5" BackgroundColor="Transparent"></ImageButton>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Tapped="ViewCell_Tapped" >
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="10"></Label>
                        <ContentView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="#666"></ContentView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

with this code behind

```
public partial class PickerCustomList : ContentPage
    {
        public int SelectedIndex = -1;
        ObservableCollection<CustomItem> myItems= new ObservableCollection<CustomItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<CustomItem> Items
        {
            get { return myItems; }
            set { 
                myItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public PickerCustomList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedIndex = -1;
            App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            MessagingCenter.Send<PickerCustomList>(this, "finish");
        }

        private void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedIndex = Items.IndexOf(((CustomItem)((ViewCell)sender).BindingContext));
            App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            MessagingCenter.Send<PickerCustomList>(this, "finish");
        }
    }
```

[image: Picker1]
[image: Picker2]